# google oAuth - how can i get data. C#.net

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0

I am a new to OAuth.
I just doing some work on that.
I have done following code. but the problem is that it opens the new window and then redirect in to the same window, it is not coming on the browser window from which (parent) it calls.

Also, can anyone tell me how can i get UserName and Email of Gmail account in to my application.

My sample code is........

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
google.load("identitytoolkit", "1.0", { packages: ["ac"] }); </script> <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    window.google.identitytoolkit.setConfig({
        developerKey: "AIzaSyAj99p8A9p5ay9E89jRHKuYZRrN3fSWp90",

        companyName: "tatvasoft",

        callbackUrl: "http://localhost:51749/Logins/Result.aspx",

        realm: "",

        userStatusUrl: "http://localhost:51749/Logins/Login.aspx",

        loginUrl: "http://localhost:51749/Logins/Login.aspx",

        signupUrl: "http://localhost:51749/Logins/Result.aspx",

        homeUrl: "http://localhost:51749/Logins/Default.aspx",

        logoutUrl: "http://localhost:51749/Logins/Default.aspx",

        language: "en",

        idps: ["Gmail", "Hotmail"],

        tryFederatedFirst: true,

        useCachedUserStatus: false

    });

    $("#navbar").accountChooser();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started 
http://havethunk.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/google-identity-toolkit-asp-net-mvc3/

Answer (score 0):

The important part is what's on your page at:

```
http://localhost:51749/Logins/Result.aspx
```

You need to have some javascript to reload the parent page, or handle the log in action in the parent window. Something like the following will work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function notify() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        // or you could use a redirect:
        // window.opener.location = "/"
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='notify();'>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are looking for a full guide for implementing Google Identity Toolkit in MVC3, I would follow the link Ali suggests: http://havethunk.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/google-identity-toolkit-asp-net-mvc3/

Alternatively, just follow the documentation on the GITKit website: http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/getting_started.html